# Where do I put this validation code if its not coming from a request?

Tags: laravel

Consider this test:

```
   public function a_slot_cant_have_the_same_start_and_end_time(){

        $this->expectException(Exception::class);

        factory(Slot::class)->create(['from'=>now(),'to'=>now()]);
    }
```

I need to test that the content of the `from` and `to` attributes are not the same. This isn't coming through a request though so I can't use the normal laravel validation (I dont think).

I've resorted to overloading the boot method on the model and using model events , but that feels hacky.

Comment: whats the problem with comparing directly, you just want to check that the contents from & to are not same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put them anywhere you want:

```
...
use Validator;
...

    $rules = [
        'field_one' => 'nullable|string|max:255',
        'field_two' => 'nullable|string|max:255',
    ];
    
    $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);
    
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        // Do what you want
    }
```

Comment: @jeremkenedy Oh nice! So I can use this within the boot method on a model? ie. within the `static::saving` event?